SSMS's GUI and dbatools produce different scripts for restoring databases in full recovery mode, what practical differences do they have?
I have a database in full recovery mode without log backups. Don't say it: I know. It fortunately isn't in an environment that I care about.
Today, disaster struck and I tried to use dbatools to generate a script to restore it. At the time, I failed. I therefore turned to SSMS's GUI and walked away with this:
BACKUP LOG [MyDb] TO DISK = N'D:\SQL\Backups\MyDb_LogBackup_Timestamp.bak'
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'D:\SQL\Backups\MyDb_LogBackup_Timestamp.bak',
NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, NORECOVERY,  STATS = 5

RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb] FROM DISK = N'X:\Backups\Full\MyDb_backup_yesterday_timestamp.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY , NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5

RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb] FROM DISK = N'X:\Backups\Full\MyDb_backup_this_morning_timestamp.dif' 
WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5

This worked great. While waiting on the restore, I got dbatools to work
Get-DbaBackupInformation -SqlInstance 'MyBox' -Path 'X:\Backups\Full\' -DirectoryRecruse -DatabaseName 'MyDb' |
Restore-DbaDatabase -OutputScriptOnly -SqlInstance 'MyBox' -WithReplace

and it produced this
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb] FROM DISK = N'X:\Backups\Full\MyDb_backup_yesterday_timestamp.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1,
MOVE N'MyDb' TO N'D:\SQL\Data\MyDb_1_.mdf',
MOVE N'MyDb_log' TO N'D:\SQL\Logs\MyDb_log1_.ldf',
NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10

RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb] FROM DISK = N'X:\Backups\Full\MyDb_backup_this_morning_timestamp.dif' 
WITH FILE = 1,
MOVE N'MyDb' TO N'D:\SQL\Data\MyDb_1_.mdf',
MOVE N'MyDb_log' TO N'D:\SQL\Logs\MyDb_log1_.ldf',
NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10

From this, it is clear that dbatools and SSMS's GUI give very different scripts for completing an identical task. In terms of the final result produced by running both, how do they differ? As far as I can tell, STATS = 10 is the only part that gives a meaningful difference.
These options are largely explained in the documentation, but there is so much information in the RESTORE DATABASE docs that I am sure to have overlooked something important. Also, you can frankly never be too careful when it comes to backups. It also surprises me that SSMS generated an entire extra command that dbatools did not and that dbatools added all of the MOVE stuff.

You won't get a "final" comprehensive answer to this, since it is impossible for us to interpret what you think is a good "explanation level".
If you are interested in an explanation in more understandable language than the documentation for some particular option for the restore command, please leave a comment here and add those to the original post.
As for the move option, SSMS will create the db files where they were when you took the backup, while dbatools is explicit to where the db files will be created. If those are the same, then they are functionally the same. I.e., if you for instance do the restore on the same server where you took the backup, then the db files are the same (obviously).
The very first command generated by SSMS it to create a log backup. SSMS doesn't create a restore command for it, though. The reason for it is that you might do an oops! So you realize your mistake and you need to re-restore the original database to the very point in time before you did the first restore. Thanks to that "last log backup" you have that option. (MS has a name for this last log backup which I'm not very fond of, and I have even forgot what they call it. But it is just a log backup performed just before the restore command...)
It does add the NORECOVERY though which means that that backup command will put the db in restoring mode. The reasoning behind this is that you are guaranteed that nobody can do any modifications after that log backup is performed and you will have the option to restore this database up to the point in time to when the first restore was done -- assuming you didn't throw away any of the backups, of course.

"MS has a name for this last log backup which I'm not very fond of, and I have even forgot what they call it." - Tail-Log Backup?

@J.D. Yes, exactly. Thank you.
